# How can I clean prefix from my pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an dataframe which looks like this:

```
ID           Name
1-10000      Max
1-11000      Peter
1-12000      Hans
```

And I need to clean the prefix from the ID number to get a dataframe like this:

```
ID           Name
10000        Max
11000        Peter
12000        Hans
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split by `-` and select by last lists for working correct if not exist `-` in `ID`:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.split('-').str[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works:)
Have a nice day :)